# Magento error: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: xml, database, magento, foreign-keys

I'm getting the following error from Magento when trying to upload products from a XML file:

> Array (
>       [id] => 1
>       [filename] => /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/temp/xmlimport/Alpha_price_046551_01.xml
>       [processed] => 0
>       [adddate] => 1386340077 ) number of records : 1000 exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`db23517_TestMagento/catalog_category_product`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON
>   DEL)' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Statement.php(320):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array) #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(546):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`ca...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/models/productsModel.php(818):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_categor...', Array) #6
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/import2.php(461):
>   ProductsModel->updateProduct(Array, NULL, Array) #7 {main} Next
>   exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db23517_TestMagento/catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON
>   DEL)' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Statement.php(320):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array) #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/lib/3rdparty/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(546):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`ca...', Array) #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/models/productsModel.php(818):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_categor...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/vhosts/8/120463/webspace/httpdocs/casesupply.nl/importer/import2.php(461):
>   ProductsModel->updateProduct(Array, NULL, Array) #6 {main}

Every night a XML file updates all my products, but recently I noticed that some products were not properly uploaded. So I deleted all my products in the database. I used a script for that. Now I want to reupload all the products from the XML file, but I keep getting this error message. Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is clear, you are attempting to update the entity field to a value that does not exist in the referenced table (category_entity table I guess) check if all the categories records exist in the referenced table before to run the query, you can try this

Answer (score 0):

I think it means you're attempting to insert a record the db thinks already exists. The error code is bitching at you telling you the records you're inserting MUST be UNIQUE.

I'd recommend checking your XML file for duplicates and making sure nothing in XML file is already in the db.